# Spark DataFrame: Count row's only if atleast one column is not null?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

Consider below data as data frame. If I do count of data frame then it's giving 6 . I want to count row's only where at east column is not null?

```
Country      id     salary
Australia   64654    NULL
NULL        NULL     NULL
Italy       23694    28
England     45585    32
NULL        NULL     NULL
Japan       NULL     10
```

Comment: Actually, the columns are not fixed and Data Frame may have 120 columns approximately . I mentioned there columns for better understanding

Comment: Hey All, I have resolved it using 'na' functions .Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about :  `df.filter($"Country".isNotNull || $"id".isNotNull || $"salary".isNotNull).count()`

Comment: Actually, the columns are not fixed and Data Frame may have 120 columns approximately . I mentioned there columns for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

Use like below will give result :-

```
select count(*) from 
(select COALESCE(*) as x from table_name) tmp 
 where x is not null
```